# Trying to connect a dbeaver database to intellij

Tags: java, database, hibernate, intellij-idea, dbeaver

I was wondering if someone could explain how to add a new mapping class for a new table in the database as i'm finding the instructions from my teacher unclear and can't commit the changes I've made without doing so.

```
<mapping class="csc1035.project2.CLASS" />        <--I need to do it here
<mapping class="csc1035.project2.CLASS" />
```

I've set up the rest of the hibernate configutation. I'm using intellij, dbeaver and mysql.

I can't find any clear explanations online

Comment: DBeaver isn't a database. It's a tool in which you can graphically show a database and it's content. DBeaver is an app, just like the one you are trying to write in intellij

Comment: Welcome to SO Nikita, the people here will need a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve. I'm myself a bit confused: Is this question about hibernate (code), , your database or your IDE / DBBeaver configuration?